# postgresql: create graph based on count of two different timestamp columns vs create_time

Tags: postgresql

So I have a table with three columns:
create_time (date of table entry), process_time (date order was processed), report_time (date order was reported). Chronologically speaking, the order is always the following: process_time > report_time > create_time.

Both process_time and report_time can be different than create_time or themselves. But the main column I want to compare against is the create_time.

I would like to create a graph where the X column is the date of create_time and the Y column is a count of how many times that create_time date appears in the process_time or report_time columns. Not a count of process_time / report_time cells which have a value, but a count of the actual date.

Very simple example:

```
| create_time | process_time | report_time |
|-------------|--------------|-------------|
| 2019-02-01  | 2019-01-27   | 2019-01-28  |
| 2019-02-20  | 2019-02-20   | 2019-02-20  |
| 2019-02-26  | 2019-02-20   | 2019-02-25  |
```

In this example the graph would show a count of 0 for the first create_time date, since there are no process_time or report_time values that match that same date. For the second create_time it would show a count of 2 process_time and 1 report time and for the third one it would show a count of 0.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand the output you want. Can you add the expect output based on your sample data, e.g. as a table just like the sample data.

Comment: It's called "chart" or "report". The "graph", especially in the context of a database, means a special data structure - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating the sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE example_table(create_time DATE, process_time DATE, report_time DATE);
INSERT INTO example_table(create_time, process_time, report_time)
VALUES ('2019-02-01', '2019-01-27', '2019-01-28'),
 ('2019-02-20', '2019-02-20', '2019-02-20'),
 ('2019-02-26', '2019-02-20', '2019-02-25');
```

The query that first selects all distinct `create_time` values and then calculates the number of appearances of that date in the `process_time` and `report_time` columns.

```
WITH create_dates AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT create_time FROM example_table
)
SELECT * FROM create_dates cd
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
           COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE cd.create_time = et.process_time) as process_time_count,
           COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE cd.create_time = et.report_time) as report_time_count
    FROM example_table et
    ) temp;
```

The result:

```
+------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| crete_time | process_time_count | report_time_count |
+------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| 2019-02-20 |          2         |         1         |
+------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| 2019-02-01 |          0         |         0         |
+------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| 2019-02-26 |          0         |         0         |
+------------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: It worked, thank you very much.

It didn't cross my mind that there might be some dates in report_time that do not appear in create_time, so I had to use a generate_series (days of current month)::date instead of create_time, and I compared against that. But it worked in the end. 

Have a great day.